# How to delete a mail sent to someone in particular and that is inside the Sent mailbox?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API with Python. I would like to delete a mail sent to someone in particular, taking into account that the mail is inside the Sent mailbox.

I found the following, but I think that it deletes mails inside the Inbox and not inside the Sent mailbox: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete

Answer (score 0):

### You can delete any message in both your incoming and sent inbox. All you need is the ID of the message.

You can obtain the latter e.g. through [listing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with optional query parameters, such as  `"to:someuser@example.com"` assigned to the query parameter `q`.

Or alternatively, if you know the thread-Id - [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) the messages belonging to this thread and choosing the one(s) you want to delete.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use `service.users().messages().delete(userId='me', id=message_to_delete['id']).execute()`, however, I am getting an error that says **Insufficient Permission**. This is the scope I defined: `SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com/'`. Can you help me please?

Comment: Your scope is correct, but if you ever changed your scopes, you should delete the token.pickle file after this before running the code. The scope issue is not related to the quality of the answer I gave you before.